# Why does this javascript output using unescape and document.write? cache breaking?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the advantage of using unescape on document.write to load javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224670/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-unescape-on-document-write-to-load-javacript)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

If the ga.js file changes, will this cause any potential issues with browser cache?  or will it always serve up the file fresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It means the code will work in XML / XHTML and HTML without having to mess with CDATA

See: [What is the advantage of using unescape on document.write to load javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224670/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-unescape-on-document-write-to-load-javascript)

Voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on server settings as to whether or not it will serve a fresh file.

As for why it writes the script tag dynamically, it's so that on secured pages (https pages) the script comes from a secure source.